# Create an object rotating outside a circle

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

**I tried to create an object rotating outside the circle, but it turns it inside the circle.**

This is what I want to do **(my character)**:

[image]

```
 func moveClockWise() {

            var dx = Character.position.x - self.frame.width / 2
            var dy = Character.position.y - self.frame.height / 2

            var rad = atan2(dy, dx)

            Path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 2), radius: 150, startAngle: rad, endAngle: rad + CGFloat(M_PI * 4), clockwise: true)
            let follow = SKAction.followPath(Path.CGPath, asOffset: false, orientToPath: true, speed: 200)
            Character.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(follow))
    }
```

**but this what happened :**

[image]

Comment: Please try to be more specific when asking questions. Explain your problem instead of just share screenshots/code.

Comment: I tried to create an object rotates outside the circle, but he turns it inside the circle.

Comment: You're using the radius of the inner circle (the blue one). Try using the radius of the outer circle (the white one)

Comment: its not blue circle its part from my background.

Comment: Then use radius + thickness of your circle.

Comment: Path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 2), radius: 150, startAngle: rad, endAngle: rad + CGFloat(M_PI * 4), clockwise: true)
            let follow = SKAction.followPath(Path.CGPath, asOffset: false, orientToPath: true, speed: 200)
            Character.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(follow))
    }

Comment: It looks like you will need to keep adjusting the rotation so that it is always facing the center as it travels the path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not going about it the exact way you are.. but this is what i came up with.  just copy paste the code and try it out :)

[image]

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    let sprite = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.redColor(), size: CGSize(width: 20, height: 30))
    let circleRadius = CGFloat(100)

    var angleRelatedToCircle = CGFloat(0)
    let rotationSpeed = CGFloat(0.01)

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        let topOfSprite = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.blueColor(), size: CGSize(width: 20, height: 2))
        topOfSprite.position.y = sprite.size.height
        sprite.addChild(topOfSprite)
        sprite.anchorPoint.y = 0
        sprite.zRotation = CGFloat(-M_PI_2)

        let circle = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: circleRadius)
        circle.fillColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
        circle.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height/2)
        self.addChild(circle)
        circle.addChild(sprite)

        sprite.position.y += circleRadius
    }


    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        sprite.zRotation += CGFloat(M_PI)
    }

    override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {
        angleRelatedToCircle -= rotationSpeed
        sprite.zRotation -= rotationSpeed

        sprite.position.x = circleRadius * cos(angleRelatedToCircle)
        sprite.position.y = circleRadius * sin(angleRelatedToCircle)
    }
}
```

Comment: i can replace the skshapenode to skspritenode?

Comment: you can make it anything you want.